# MacBook 7,1 randomly shutting down (shutdown cause -102)

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, shutdown, motherboard

I have a MacBook 7,1 (mid 2010) and sometimes it randomly shuts down. This *only* happens when I am doing something very resource intensive (like gaming). After the shutdown I can use my Mac for "normal" things without any issues, but as soon as I do the same thing as before the shutdown, it will shutdown again.

When checking the console, it says "Previous shutdown cause: -102". The only thing I could find was "Overvoltage shutdown protection", but I wouldn't know why there would be an overvoltage. Disconnecting the charger and using the battery doesn't help.

<s>Resetting the SMC seems to help, but after a month or so the problem starts occurring again.</s> I ran an Apple Hardware Test (both regular and extended version) and it doesn't find any issues. What can be causing this? Is it an issue with the motherboard?

*Just to make sure: Is it possible that it's the 6Gbps SSD (Samsung 860 EVO) that I installed (while my Mac officially only supports 3Gbps), somehow messing things up?*

Comment: Negative shutdown codes are related to hardware.  Over voltage is likely a CPU or GPU issue, so yes, the logic board.  As far as your drives go, they are backward compatible so a SATA III drive in a SATA II slot will be fine (btw, it's 6Gb/s or 3Gb/s - 3G is something completely different)

Comment: I know there is backwards compatibility, but I've read about people still having issues with this with certain drives. For example, the OWC SSD's would sometimes give issues with older MacBooks, with even data corruption as a result.

Comment: Yes, there was corruption, because OWC implemented RAID on the drives (for whatever reason).  That’s an OWC issue not a SATA level issue.

Answer (score 0):

On a ten-year-old laptop with a non-removable battery, I suspect that the battery chemistry has aged to the point that it can't reliably provide an appropriate supply of power. I'm vaguely surprised that it's *over* voltage protection, but the chemistry of an aging battery is a complex topic.

[iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+Battery+Replacement/4300) indicates that you can get a replacement battery for $95 and that the replacement process is easy (only five steps!). Their guides are generally excellent, and this one looks like no exception. They'll even sell you the weird trilobe screwdriver you need to pull it off.

Even if this doesn't solve your problem, it will almost certainly improve your overall experience with this aging laptop.

Comment: The battery is not "non-removable", as I already had to take it out a year ago to adjust the screw in the trackpad. But how can it be the battery if I almost always use my charger? And the weird thing is that the shutdowns only happen if I'm doing more resource-intensive things.

Comment: By "non-removable", I meant that you have to open up the case to do it; it's inside the unibody. For comparison, my old 2008 MPB (RIP) just had a little latch underneath you could slide which allowed the entire battery to pop right out.

Comment: The battery is _always_ responsible for the power used by the system. The charger, when connected, is simply replenishing that at the same time. More resource-intensive activity nonetheless complicates that, and charging _during_ more resource-intensive activity increases battery temperature, which increases the likelihood of such faults. I hadn't thought of this before, but it also helps explain the overvoltage situation, as battery chargers normally provide slightly more voltage than the battery's nominal rating.

Comment: TLDR: spend that $100 and replace the battery! Pro-tip: don't look for something cheaper. Cheap batteries are almost always junk.

Comment: Your info about the charger is incorrect. I don’t know where you’re getting that info from, but not only does it not make sense, it’s refuted by anyone who has any board level experience with MacBooks.  You don’t even know what exactly is measuring over voltage, but your assigning it to the battery.

Comment: @Allan I'm definitely not trying to say that the _battery_ is measuring the voltage. Apologies if I was unclear. Which info, exactly, is incorrect? Please feel free to set me straight.

Comment: I just noticed the battery status says "Maintenance required". Not sure for how long it's been saying that but I can't remember having seen it before. @Allan can this be related to my shutdown issue?

Comment: @Priv - yes - a faulty battery *can* cause issues especially if it's not holding a charge and you're doing resource intensive work (i.e. gaming).  Over voltage could be that both your system and battery are *drawing* (requesting) more power than your power supply can deliver

Comment: @Allan Shutdowns happen both with and without the charger. Anyway, I'll see if I can get a replacement battery.